# Convert String to object in java

Tags: java

I have a HashSet in where I need to store the available ingredients.

```
HashSet<Ingredient> availableIngreds = new HashSet<>();
```

The available ingredients are read from a file.

```
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));       
    while (file.hasNext()) {
        availableIngreds.add(file.next());             //Non working code
    }

    System.out.println("*** Available ingredients ***");
    for (Ingredient i : availableIngreds) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

My problem is that the file contains the ingredients as strings (flour, sugar, milk etc).

My HashSet needs to store the ingredients as object of the class Ingredient.

How can I convert String to Ingredient so the above line of code works? 
Thank you for your help.

*** edit ***
class Ingredient:

```
public class Ingredient {

    private String iName;

    public Ingredient(String aName) {
        iName = aName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return iName; 
    }

    public String toString() { 
        return iName; 
    }

    public boolean equals(Object rhs) {
        return iName.equals(((Ingredient)rhs).iName);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return iName.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't help you without seeing `Ingredient`. The simple answer is: `Ingredient` itself just needs to have a method that does the work, or (if there's a hierarchy) you'll want an `IngredientFactory` that knows about the hierarchy and can do the mapping. There's no magic "do this and it'll work" solution, you just have to do the work.

Comment: You must create new Ingredient object and send him your string or his variable, in the contractor or other place convert the string to Ingredient variables..

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have added the Ingredient class now.

Comment: You have constructor which accepts name of ingredient as String: `public Ingredient(String aName) {iName = aName;}`. Why not use it with result of `next()`?

Comment: Thank you @Pshemo, that is exacty what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a constructor for `Ingredient` that accepts a String. Just use it when adding values to your HashSet:

```
while (file.hasNext()) {
    availableIngreds.add(new Ingredient(file.next()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `file.next()` returns a `String`, and you need to create in `Ingredient` object from it, overload the constructors with one that take a `String` as a parameter (I'm assuming that your `Ingredient` class has a `String` field in which you store the actual ingredient name), create the `Ingredient` object you want with it and then store it in your `Hashmap`.